# How to sort javascript objects based on their properties, specifying the property

Tags: javascript, sorting

There are lots of answers on SO for similar questions, which all describe how to implement a custom sort function to sort an array of javascript objects.

However, I was wondering if it might be possible to implement a more abstract custom sort that would allow me to pass the name of the property of the objects on which I want it to sort. This might save me having to implement very similar functions over and over again.

So if I had an object constructor like:

```
function Car(mph, cc) {
    this.maxSpeed = mph;
    this.engineSize = cc;
}
```

then instead of implementing two sort functions:

```
function sortCarsOnMaxSpeed(a, b) { return a.maxSpeed - b.maxSpeed; }
function sortCarsOnEngineSize(a, b) { return a.engineSize - b.engineSize; }
```

I could have some sort of generic function such as:

```
function sortObjectsOnProperty(a, b, property) {
    return a[property] - b[property];
}
```

but the custom sort seems to only take 2 arguments.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write a function that takes a property name and returns a comparator:

```
function createComparator(property) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a[property] - b[property];
    };
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
arr.sort(createComparator("maxSpeed"));
```

Comment: function createComparator(property) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1
        if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1
        return 0
    };
}

This works for string comparison to

Answer (score 2):

`sort` takes a function, which can be anonymous:

```
sort(array, function(a, b) { return a.maxSpeed - b.maxSpeed; });
```

If you really don't want this, you can define a sortObjectsOnProperty() function that return a sort callback like this:

```
function sortObjectsOnProperty(name) {
    return function(a, b) { return a[name] - b[name]; }
}
```