# Populate the dropdown in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to populate my drop down in certain order (alphabetical order/alpha numeric order), but my code doesn't seems to be working. It is populating the value but not in order.

Here is my code

```
function dropdown(){
    var html = html + "<option value='All'>All</option>";
    var colValue = getColumn("COLUMN");
    for( var i = 0; i < colValue.length; i++ ) {
        var valueRow = colValue[i];
        html = html + "<option value='" + valueRow.c + "'>" + valueRow.c + "-" + valueRow.v + "</option>";
    }
    $('#id').append(html);    

}
```

here, COLUMN is the key that holds the value A1,A2,A3,B1

this code populate my drop down in the order A3,A1,A2,B1

I want my drop down to populate in the order A1,A2,A3,B1

while i did `alert(html);`i get the result

```
<option value='All'>All   </option>";
<option value='A3'>A3-a3Value </option>";
<option value='A2'>A1-a2Value </option>";
<option value='A1'>A2-a1Value </option>";
<option value='B1'>B1-b1Value </option>";
```

and it is populating exactly in the same order.

My question is, what i need to do, to populate my dropdown in order? 
I'm still in the beginner phase in java script and Jquery.  Appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: if you create a jsFiddle that shows the issue, it makes it easier to help :) Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are saying, it looks like colValue looks like this:

```
colValue = [
  { c="A3", v="a3Value" },
  { c="A1", v="a2Value" } // etc.
]
```

So you will need to decide what property to sort on, and then you can create a comparator:

```
function createComparator(property) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a[property] > b[property];
    };
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
colValue.sort(createComparator("c"));
```

Based on this SO answer: [How to sort javascript objects based on their properties, specifying the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462766/how-to-sort-javascript-objects-based-on-their-properties-specifying-the-propert)

Comment: @David - I just fixed a logic error in the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function dropdown(){
    var html = html + "<option value='All'>All</option>";
    var colValue = getColumn("COLUMN");
    colValue.sort();
    for( var i = 0; i < colValue.length; i++ ) {
        var valueRow = colValue[i];
        html = html + "<option value='" + valueRow.c + "'>" + valueRow.c + "-" + valueRow.v + "</option>";
    }
    $('#id').append(html);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `valueRow` is an object instead of an array and you want to sort on `valueRow.v` you need more than `Array.sort()`.

Take a look at lodash's `sortBy`: http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

`_.sortBy(valueRow, 'c')`