# How I build a reorder Array Object Methods fetching Swapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Film grid that return their Id, thumbnail, title, episode number and released date.

How can I map reorderByDate() & reorderByEpisode() methods for return reorders values?

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2574xp1oz) & [Api Documentation Swapi](https://swapi.co/)

**Films.js Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ListFilms from './ListFilms'

class Films extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      films: [],
    }

    this.getFilms = this.getFilms.bind(this)
  }

  getFilms() {
    return axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/films')
      ...
      })
  }

  reorderByDate = () => {
    let films = this.state.films.map(item => ({ ...item }));
    films.sort((a, b) =>
      a.release_date > b.release_date
        ? 1
        : b.release_date > a.release_date
        ? -1
        : 0
    );
    this.setState({ films });
  };

  reorderByEpisode = () => {
    let films = this.state.films.map(item => ({ ...item }));
    films.sort((a, b) =>
      a.episode_id > b.episode_id ? 1 : b.episode_id > a.episode_id ? -1 : 0
    );
    this.setState({ films });
  };

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getFilms();
  }
  render() {
    const { films } = this.state;
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-2">
          <p className="mb-0 mr-2">Filter by:</p>
          <button onClick={this.reorderByDate} type="button" className="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Released Date</button>
          <p className="mb-0 mx-2">or:</p>
          <button onClick={this.reorderByEpisode} type="button" className="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Episode Number</button>
        </div>
        <ListFilms films={films} />
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Films;
```

Comment: simply sort the state films array pass the returned value to films prop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort javascript objects based on their properties, specifying the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462766/how-to-sort-javascript-objects-based-on-their-properties-specifying-the-propert) and [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216) and [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666)

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://codesandbox.io/s/r5o56mz2zn ? you need to sort films array for both the problems

Comment: Thks! I rebuild reorder methods like arrow functions for fix an issue of films scope.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the current scenario, you can use `onClick()` listeners on the buttons, and either use arrow operator or bind function to `this`

Inside the function, use `Array.prototype.sort` method to implement custom logic for sorting based on date or episode number

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You should use `this.setState(prevState => nextState)` functional syntax since you are trying to update films array from the exisiting state object to a sorted array and re-render

Comment: But i did what you say and add onClick events and arrows functions. Now i'm block traing to get films values inside of methods.

Answer (score 0):

please use the updated code from https://codesandbox.io/s/zn923169mx

```
reorderByDate = () => {
    let films = this.state.films;
    // let films = this.state.films;
    //console.log("from real",films[0].release_date);
    films = films.sort((a, b) => {
      let date1 = new Date(a.release_date).getTime();
      let date2 = new Date(b.release_date).getTime();
      console.log(date1);
      return date1 - date2;
    });
    this.setState({ films });
  };

  reorderByEpisode = () => {
    // console.log(...films.episode_id);
    let films = this.state.films;
    films = films.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.episode_id - b.episode_id;
    });
    this.setState({ films });
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of sorting the movies by `release_date`.This is basic idea you can use it to sort on other basis. Add `renderByDate()` to `Films` and the button in `Films` container to to call the method

```
//add this button in your `Films` component
<button onClick={this.renderByDate}>Render By Date</button>

renderByDate = () => {
    let films = this.state.films;
    //console.log("from real",films[0].release_date);
    films = films.sort((a, b) => {
      let date1 = new Date(a.release_date).getTime()
      let date2 = new Date(b.release_date).getTime()
      console.log(date1);
      return date1 - date2;
    });
    this.setState({ films });
  };
```